# Consistent extension of $\pi$-system to algebra

Tags: probability, abstract-algebra, measure-theory

Suppose you are given the $\pi$-system $\mathcal{C}$ and the pre-measure $p$ and let $\mathcal{A}$ be the minimal Algebra containing $\mathcal{C}$.

I am looking for a method to explicitly extend the pre-measure on $\mathcal{C}$ to a premeasure on $\mathcal{A}$. Ideally, this looks like an application of the inclusione-exclusion formula, but that does not seem applicable as, for example, in orded to give a coherent value to the premeasure of $E \cup F^\complement$ one would need the premeasure of $E \cap F^\complement$. And this is just the same as the union, under De Morgan laws.

Comment: I don't think the formula for $\mathcal A$ is correct.  It would be correct if you knew $\mathcal{C}\cup\mathcal{C'}$ was a $\pi$-system.  You're only given that $\mathcal C$ is a $\pi$-system.  You still need to close $\mathcal{C}\cup\mathcal{C'}$ under finite intersections.

Comment: Then i suppose that is why inclusion-exclusion is not up for it. Let me fix the question.

Comment: The inclusion-exclusion principle is up for it.  $A_1\cap A_2^\complement\cap\ldots\cap A_n^\complement=(A_1\cup\ldots\cup A_n)\setminus(A_2\cup\ldots\cup A_n)$.